# I want to find the fourier spectrum of an image

Tags: image, fft, frequency, dft

Is this correct? `p1` is the source image and `p2` the destination image and all the 3 channels have the same value as I am working with grayscale image and `pp1[i]` accesses the 'ith' channel.

```
for(int x=0;x<height;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;y<width;y++)
    {
        pp1=pixel1+x*rowstride+y*n_channels;
        pp2=pixel2+x*rowstride+y*n_channels;
        for(int xx=0;xx<height;xx++)
        {
            for(int yy=0;yy<width;yy++)
            {
                real=real+pp1[0]*cos(2*3.14*yy*y/width+2*3.14*xx*x/height);
                imag=imag-pp1[0]*sin(2*3.14*yy*y/width+2*3.14*xx*x/height);
            }
        }
        temp=sqrt(real*real+imag*imag);

        pp2[0]=(int)temp;
        pp2[1]=(int)temp;
        pp2[2]=(int)temp;
    }
}
```